# Convert matrix of kitchen things to ascii translation

Tags: python

I was given this interview question

In a game, we have to render a matrix of kitchen items into actual graphics. To do this, you are
given a matrix info of kitchen items of the form-

```
<height, width of room>
<item_type> <x position> <y position>
```

for example

```
<2,2>
sugar 0,1
spoons 1,1
```

This corresponds to a sugar at 01 and 1 spoon at 11

Generate a ASCII translation sugar (blank being empty squares)

```
Blank Blank 
Sugar Spoon
```

Do this for arbit input assuming you have no memory overflows

I looped over content, wrote a for loop but my code had errors. What's the best way to do this? Create a dictionary or size NxN and loop over itand put in blanks or items?

Comment: What's the code you have tried?

Comment: This question is opinion-based and will likely be answered with opinions instead of facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
t="""<2,2>
sugar 0,1
spoons 1,1"""

l = t.split('\n')

h, w = l[0].strip('>').strip('<').split(',')
kitchen = [['Blank']*int(w) for i in range(int(h))]

for line in l[1:]:
    item, location = line.split(' ')
    i, j = location.split(',')
    kitchen[int(j)][int(i)] = item
print(kitchen)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no specific answer for this question. But maybe something like this would be fine:

```py
In [10]: def get_board_size(): 
    ...:     return map(int, input().strip('<>').split(',')) 
    ...: 

In [11]: def arrange(w, h): 
    ...:     board = [['Blank' for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)] 
    ...:     while (inp := input()) != 'q': 
    ...:         text, coordinates = inp.split() 
    ...:         x, y = map(int, coordinates.split(',')) 
    ...:         board[x][y] = text 
    ...:     return board 
    ...: 

In [12]: def main(): 
    ...:     w, h = get_board_size() 
    ...:     board = arrange(w, h) 
    ...:     print('\n------------ Result ------------') 
    ...:     for row in board: 
    ...:         print(' '.join(row)) 
    ...:         print() 
    ...: 

In [13]: main()
<2,2>
Sugar 0,1
Spoon 1,1
q

------------ Result ------------
Blank Sugar

Blank Spoon
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with a dictionary,
it's more efficient when room [matrix is sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) in comparison to a matrix representation, as empty cells won't be saved.
However, I've encapsulated the Room representation in an object, thus enabling to change the representation yet keeping the useful methods intact.

```
import re

input = \
"""
<2,2>
sugar 0,1
spoons 1,1
"""

class Room:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.items  = dict()

    def add_item(self, item_type, x_position, y_position):
        if x_position > self.height or y_position > self.width:
            raise Exception(f'Invalid position ({x_position},{y_position}) for matrix size [{self.height},{self.width}]')
        self.items[(x_position, y_position)] = item_type

    def __str__(self):
        BLANK_NAME              = 'Blank'
        SPACES_BETWEEN_CELLS    = 2
        str                     = ''
        for y_position in range(self.width):
            for x_position in range(self.height):
                item_type = self.items.get((x_position, y_position), BLANK_NAME)
                str += SPACES_BETWEEN_CELLS * ' ' + item_type.capitalize()
            str += '\n'
        return str

def parse_numbers_from_string(str, seperators=''):
    return [int(s) for s in re.split(seperators, str) if s.isdigit()]

def parse_lines_from_string(str):
    lines = str.split('\n')
    return [x for x in lines if x]

def parse(input, seperators='\<|\>| |,'):
    lines = parse_lines_from_string(input)
    height, width = parse_numbers_from_string(lines[0], seperators)
    room = Room(height, width)
    for line_number in range(1, len(lines)):
        item_type = lines[line_number].split()[0]
        x_position, y_position = parse_numbers_from_string(lines[line_number], seperators)
        room.add_item(item_type, x_position, y_position)
    return room

if '__main__' == __name__:
    room = parse(input)
    print(room)
```